# Chatter email links - Community

Tags: community, email, chatter, chatter-feed, notification

I currently have some internal users that try to access links from the chatter notification emails for a community. The links do not point to the community-specific pages. I would really like for the email notifications to be the community-specific emails with the correct links. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Right now the workflow is:
An internal user gets tagged in a community chatter post. The internal user gets the internal org email notification that they've been tagged. The user clicks on the link and the link takes them to the internal org page for that post.

I would like the workflow to be that the user gets the community branded emails with the community links so that when the user clicks on the links they are taken to the community page of the post in which they were tagged.

The first thing I tried was to turn off the user's internal chatter notification settings while keeping the community settings on for that user. This led to the user receiving no emails about any notifications.

Comment: Are you saying that an Internal User always receives an email from Community on Chatter notifications but on clicking links on that email is always redirected to Internal Org instead of Community?

Comment: I updated the original question so that it hopefully answers this. I would like the internal users to only get community branded emails with the community links.

Comment: I had faced this issue, just the other way round, that we did not want the Users to go the Community and that they were always redirected to the Community. I think this is just related to that. Can you confirm that on the User details, if there's a value in the Default Community? If not, try adding the Community that you want the User to be redirected on Chatter notifications. That should probably resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were in this situation sometime back, but the other way round, i.e., all links on Chatter notification emails wherever Internal Users were mentioned, redirected to the Community. Whereas we wanted it to be redirected to the Internal Org.

Upon investigating, we found out this mentioned on [Chatter email notifications direct user to community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193175&type=1) knowledge article.

> The affected user's assigned profile has been assigned a default community. All emails sent would whether for internal chatter mentions would be branded for the default community. See [Assign a Default Community to a User Profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=network_affinity.htm&type=5) for more details.

We had to remove the Default Community assignment from the User to be able to redirect all links in Chatter email notifications to be redirected to Internal Org.

Your use case is just the opposite, but this should help you to achieve it. You will need to make sure that a *Default Community* is added on the affected User's profile. Once done, all links on the Chatter notification email should then redirect the User to respective Community.

Comment: This seems to have done it. My internal users are now getting directed to the place I want, which is the community. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know. We had literally struggled a lot with this.